# Why is it impossible to create an std::set<const std::string> in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, compiler-errors, clang

I have a class with `std::set<const std::string>` members which compiles fine in Clang 10.0.1 on macOS, but does not with GCC 5.4.0. MRE below

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

class Foo {
  std::set<const std::string> bar; ///<--- error ‘const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference) const [with _Tp = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_pointer = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&]’ cannot be overloaded

public:
  Foo() {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Foo f;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler invocation:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

If instead I use non-const `string` it works.
Is this a problem of an outdated standard library version?

Comment: @ChrisMM, cppreference lists the `CopyAssignable` requirement for `T` in the case of `std::vector`, but there is no such a requirement for `std::set`.

Comment: @Evg, it's the allocator that has the requirement … Which set uses

Comment: Interesting, so the fact that Clang compiles this is implementation-defined behaviour or simply a standards violation?

Comment: It is not a violation because requirements on `T` are broadened, not narrowed.

Comment: I can't seem to find specification of this behaviour in cppreference.com. Can it only be deduced from the actual standard text or am I missing something?

Comment: I used the standard draft. In n4713, it's Table 30 for the requirements of allocator (`[allocator.requirements]`)

Comment: [Here it is](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements#tab:allocator.req.var).